# Gmail IMAP search by multiple senders

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

This search query seems valid to me :

```
UID SEARCH OR ( OR ( OR (FROM "def@gmail.com") (FROM "abc@gmail.com")) (FROM "ghi@gmail.com")) (FROM "jkl@gmail.com")
```

but I got "Could not parse command" error when trying to query that command to Gmail IMAP.

I tried

> UID SEARCH OR  OR  OR FROM "def@gmail.com" FROM "abc@gmail.com"  FROM
>   "ghi@gmail.com"  FROM "jkl@gmail.com"

and

> UID SEARCH OR (FROM "jkl@gmail.com") ( OR (FROM "ghi@gmail.com") ( OR
>   (FROM "abc@gmail.com") (FROM "def@gmail.com")))

and

> UID SEARCH OR  OR  OR FROM def@gmail.com FROM abc@gmail.com FROM
>   ghi@gmail.com FROM jkl@gmail.com

all failed with "Could not parse command".

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you have a mailbox selected or else it will not work.  Secondly, make sure you are prefixing your commands with a tag or else IMAP will interpret your UID command as a tag and will actually execute the SEARCH command and not a UID command.

Finally, try building your search query *slowly*.  The following commands worked for me:

```
tag UID SEARCH FROM "def@gmail.com"
tag UID SEARCH OR FROM "def@gmail.com" FROM "abc@gmail.com"
tag UID SEARCH OR OR FROM "def@gmail.com" FROM "abc@gmail.com" FROM "blah@hotmail.com"
tag UID SEARCH OR OR OR FROM "def@gmail.com" FROM "abc@gmail.com" FROM "blah@hotmail.com" FROM "dah@bah.com"
```